# Leet Code Regular Expression Matching Problem

Tags: c++

https://leetcode.com/problems/regular-expression-matching

I was doing this practice problem (cpp) and while faster solutions are in the comments, I would like to understand why my code isn't working. This fails with `s = "mississippi"` and `p = "mis*is*p*."`. Tracing through the code, I figured it would correctly remove the first two letters, then when seeing the s* it would go through the s in the string (two of them), then remove the i in both, remove all the s (again 2) then remove all the p's (which is none, because it's compared against the i in the first string, so it should not modify that string). Finally, the '.' would match with the first p and remove both. So the final string should be "pi" and return false when the length is compared to zero.

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isMatch(string s, string p) {
        
        while (s.length() > 0){
            if (p.length() == 0){
                return false;
            }else if (p.length() == 1){
                return p.compare(s) == 0 || p.at(0) == '.';
            }else{
                if (p.at(1) == '*'){
                    char c = p.at(0);
                    p = p.substr(2);
                    if (c == '.'){
                        return true;
                    }
                    int spot = 0;
                    while(spot < s.length() && s.at(spot) == c){
                        spot++;
                    }
                    if (spot != 0){
                    s = s.substr(spot);
                    }
                }else{
                    if (s.at(0) != p.at(0) && p.at(0) != '.'){
                        return false;
                    }
                    s = s.substr(1);
                    p = p.substr(1);
                }
            }
        }
        return s.length() == 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: For codeblocks, use three backticks `\`` not single quotes `'`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without external links and explain what your code is supposed to do

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is faulty here

```
return p.compare(s) == 0 || p.at(0) == '.';
```

That should be

```
return p.compare(s) == 0 || (s.length() == 1 && p.at(0) == '.');
```

That took me five minutes to find, two minutes looking at the code without seeing the problem, and then three minutes using a debugger to track down the logic error. You really should learn to use a debugger, much more efficient than asking on SO.

Some tips [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Didn't work for all cases but the lesson from this is clear- I need to just learn how to use a debugger and figure it out myself after. thank you